# Migrate existing RAID5 to RAID10 with new disks

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssd, raid

I have the following situation:
Within my Server, i have a RAID5 and RAID1 made out of 3 x 3TB HDDs. Now i want to migrate the whole stuff to a RAID10 made out of 4 x 1TB SSDs.

Actually i have SW RAID5 with LVM and EXT4.

This is how it looks actually:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md128 : active raid5 sdc3[2] sdb3[1] sda3[0]
      5840248832 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]
      bitmap: 7/22 pages [28KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active raid1 sdc2[2] sdb2[1] sda2[0]
      9756672 blocks super 1.2 [3/3] [UUU]
```

md128 is for data
md0 is the boot stuff.

Now im not sure about the perfect procedure.
I have only one SATA slot left.

PLAN A:

My idea was:

1. Backup md0 and md128 using rsync to an additional, external disk.
2. Remove all disks, insert all SSDs, boot from USB-Stick into a live Ubuntu version
3. Create a RAID1 (for booting) and RAID10 (for Data)
4. Add LVM on top (for later snapshots)
5. Create volume groups and format them with EXT4
6. Restore all Data from the external HDD

Sounds easy, but the details are not that clear for me at the moment.

Would be great if someone could assist me during this process.
Is there an easier way compared to what i have planned?
Thank you.

PLAN B:

My idea was:

1. Backup md0 and md128 using rsync to an additional, **internal (using the left over slot)** disk.
2. Remove all disks, **expect for the backup one**, insert all (3) SSDs, boot from USB-Stick into a live Ubuntu version
3. Create a RAID1 (for booting) and RAID10 **(a degraded one, with only 3 SSD)** (for Data)
4. Add LVM on top (for later snapshots)
5. Create volume groups and format them with EXT4
6. Restore all Data **from the additional internal** HDD
7. Format the last backup disk and add these to the degraded RAID10
8. The RAID10 should now be in an active state.

Pros of PLAN B, i can use the internal SATA Slot and dont have to mess around with external USB HDDs.

Comment: Plan B is prone to errors.

If your server has USB 3/3.1/3.2 speed is not such a bottleneck anymore, so I'd go with Plan A

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Yes i do have USB3.2 i will go with Plan A. I saw that the RAID1 was soley used for swap. I think i will use only RAID10 also for swap this time. RAM is large enough. Therefore i dont think that swap will be used…

Comment: just aside: get acquainted with ZFSonLinux ... really useful, no need to run LVM on top, snapshots included, if your server has some "time" left, use deduplication, online-compression etc.

Comment: Hmm sounds interesting. I dont have preasure to switch to RAID10. I can also wait weeks more. What would be the stack? RAID10 -> ZFS?

Comment: i had a look at ZFS. Looks not that bad. but i use https://www.virtualmin.com/ for administrating the server and i dont know whether this can use ZFS

Comment: raid10 would be a striped mirror in zfs terminology. zfs describes its levels by the amount of parity drives, so a raid5 would be raidz1, raid6 would be raidz2. you could even go further and have raidz3 ...

sorry, can't tell you about virtualmin, since i don't use ist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133800/discussion-between-c-hediger-and-bigsn).